# Trigger a popup alert message using checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, standardcontroller, popup

I am trying to display a pop-up alert with a message on the uncheck of checkbox. I am using Standard controller and need to implement this functionality on the Contact Page Layout. I have a custom checkbox field: `Customer__c` (default unchecked).

What my requirement is that when I check this,it should save normally (this is happening) but when some user tries to uncheck it, that user should get a pop-up alert with the message.

I have created a VF page for the same and a controller class. I have placed the VF page on the Standard Contact Page Layout keeping the Height as 0. But whenever I uncheck and try to save the record, the pop-up doesn't show up. What am I missing in my code (I don't get any compile/debug errors).

Below is the code for VF:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Contact" rendered="{!(Contact.Customer__c)}" >

<script type="text/javascript">

var msg="Unchecking this box will imply that the user has churned and will automatically de-activate in the Admin Panel.If you dont want that to happen, kindly check the box again";

    function throwalert{
       if ( {!Contact.Customer__c} == false)
       {
          alert(msg); setAlertVal();
       }
     }
     window.onclick = throwalert();
</script>
</apex:page>
```

This is the code for the controller:

```
public class PopUpAlert
{
public Contact cont;

  public PopUpAlert(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

   Contact cont = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    cont=[select id,Customer__c from Contact where Id=: cont.ID];

  }
  public void setAlertVal(){
     cont.Customer__c = false;
     update cont;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your original goal is prevent user uncheck the Customer__c flag on a Contact record, you can simple make the field disabled (read-only) on the page Layout. See [Control User Access to Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layoutoverview.htm&type=5)

**Answer to the question "Why popup does not appear"**.

Please look at the code below:

```
if ( {!Contact.Customer__c} == false)
```

When a VF page renders this part `{!Contact.Customer__c}` transforms into `true`, since at the time of rendering this flag was actually `true`. When you uncheck this field, it does not change change in the part of of your JavaScript function because at this time you rendered VF page looks like:

```
if ( true == false)
```

**Possible solution.**

***Option 1.*** Unfortunately, there is no a simple way to add an event listener to the standard  element on a standard page. Though you can try adding a listener to the Customer__c field from your VF page, and assign a handler that would show a popup each time the checkbox is unchecked.

***Option 2.*** Create a custom VF page which is a full copy of you standard Contact Page. Here it would be easier to add event listeners to the fields.

Comment: Hi, well we don't want any user to prevent from unchecking.  We want to display an alert pop up when they try to uncheck it. Like I said, it is unchecked by default but can be checked. Once checked, it should give the message and if they still want to go about it, they still can uncheck it.

Answer (score -2):

Just try this below Javascript

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c"   
    rendered="{!Book__c.Manufacturing_Date__c!= Null}"> <script   
    type="text/javascript"> window.alert("After manufacturing date you  
    must enterd descriptin"); </script>    </apex:page>
```

Comment: How does this code help solve the original problem? The popup alert should appear only when the user unchecks the Customer__c field. In your example an alert will always appear when the VF is rendered.

Comment: Hi Eduard,
You know I'm Just tried.
Here below line of coding will definelty show an alert try that please
`<apex:inputfield value="{!Lead.SA_Check__c}" onchange="if ( (this.checked) && (!alert('Are you sure?')) ){this.checked=true}"/ >`